# date in textbox with the format yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: javascript, html, date

how can i have automatic current date in the text box when i load the page with the format yyyy-mm-dd

```
       <tr><td>*Date:</td></tr>
 <tr><td><div id="ma"><input type="text" name="dte" id="text1">  </div> 
  <script type="text/javascript">    
   document.getElementById("text1").value = Date().toString();    
 </script>    
  </td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to write a date in ISO 8601 format in JavaScript. There are several ways to do it. The following is a simple plain JavaScript way and works across browsers:

```
function toISO8601(date) {
  var d  = date.getDate();
  if(d < 10) d = '0' + d;
  var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
  if(m < 10) m = '0' + m;
  return date.getFullYear() + '-' + m + '-' +  d;
}
document.getElementById("text1").value = toISO8601(Date());
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation so that I cannot add the comments to Mike.

Just like Mike's solution, but there are some small mistakes:

1. `getDay()` return the weekday a number (0-6), so you should use `getDate()`
2. `getMonth()` return 0-11, so you should +1.

   ```
   var d = new Date();

   var day = d.getDate();
   var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
   var year = d.getFullYear();

   if (Math.floor(day / 10) === 0) {
       day = "0" + day;
   }
   if (Math.floor(month / 10) === 0) {
       month = "0" + month;
   }

   document.getElementById("text1").value = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
   ```

Comment: @vol7ron, I explained why I did not add a comment. And thanks you for letting me know I can edit other people's answer.

Comment: Let me give you some reputation :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be just doing something like this:

```
var d = new Date();

var day = d.getDate();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var year = d.getFullYear();

if (Math.floor(day / 10) === 0) {
    day = "0" + day;
}
if (Math.floor(month / 10) === 0) {
    month = "0" + month;
}

document.getElementById("text1").value = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
```

EDIT: Fixed errors caught by Guozi.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a lot of formatting, you may want to consider [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).  With it, you could easily set the value using:

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

If you are only formatting that one date, then it may not be worth the overhead, but as a library, it permits you to keep your site-specific JS clean.

Answer (score 0):

When using php this is also a good option:

```
<input type="text" name="dte" id="text1" value="<?= date("Y-m-d") ?>">
```